# PHP Ajax , Not able to pass a PHP value from one page to another using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a php code that post value using ajax to another php page , but the value provided is not reflecting in UI nor in console .

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#CustomerName').click(function() {
    customername = $(this).text();
    load_data(customername);
    //  console.log(customername); //  works 
  });



  function load_data(Customername) {
    // console.log(Customername); // works 
    $.ajax({
      url: "getvalueafterclick.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        Customername: Customername,
        EnvironmentType: "BA"
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("some error occured->" + jqXHR.responseJSON);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<?php
// perform actions for each file found
foreach (glob("CustomerConfigFiles/*.json") as $filename) {
      echo ' <a href="#" id ="CustomerName" class="mm-active">
      <i class="metismenu-icon pe-7s-rocket"></i>'.substr(substr($filename,20), 0, -5).'</a>';
}
?>
```

So when i give console.log  in function and onclick , it returns value but when i try to pass CustomerName , it just returns null .

**getvalueafterclick.php**

```
<?php
$pat =$_POST['EnvironmentType'];
$lat =$_POST['Customername'];
echo "<script>console.log('Customer Name: " . $lat . "');</script>"; 
echo "<script>console.log('ENVIRON: " . $pat . "');</script>"; 

?>
```

Here is output i get :
[image: Console Image]

Comment: Do you know the difference between id's and classes?

Comment: yes @EmielZuurbier, i posted this to know answer and you are asking me questions again

Comment: The difference between an ID and a class is that an ID can be used to identify one element, whereas a class can be used to identify more than one.  @EmielZuurbier

Comment: Yes, so only your first element in the loop will work with the click function, because your id will not be unique. But the problem lies in the output of your elements. Currently it's PHP, but we can't imagine what the generated HTML will look like and what the `text()` value of the anchor element is. Instead of showing us the PHP which you generate the HTML with, show the actual HTML.

Comment: Please show your ajax request headers, body and response.

Answer (score 1):

Change id to class for CustomerName  , I have added/ changed your code, see if it helps to solve your problem.

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
      // changed # to . for class
          $('.CustomerName').click(function() {
            customername = $(this).text();
            load_data(customername);
            //  console.log(customername); //  works 
          });
    
    
    
          function load_data(Customername) {
            // console.log(Customername); // works 
            $.ajax({
              url: "getvalueafterclick.php",
              method: "POST",
              data: {
                Customername: Customername,
                EnvironmentType: "BA"
              },
              success: function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
               // console added to check what it is giving
                console.log(data);
              },
              error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("some error occured->" + jqXHR.responseJSON);
              }
            });
          }
        });
```

```html
    <?php

     //your code
    // perform actions for each file found
// here in link change id to class for customer name 
    foreach (glob("CustomerConfigFiles/*.json") as $filename) {
          echo ' <a href="#" class="CustomerName" class="mm-active">
          <i class="metismenu-icon pe-7s-rocket"></i>'.substr(substr($filename,20), 0, -5).'</a>';
    }

// my testing code 

        $data =["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"];
     // perform actions for each file found
    // here in link change id to class for customer name 
        foreach ($data as $filename) {
              echo ' <a href="#" class="CustomerName" class="mm-active">
              <i class="metismenu-icon pe-7s-rocket"></i>'.$filename.'</a>';
        }
   
    


   ?>


    getvalueafterclick.php
      <?php
      $pat =$_POST['EnvironmentType'];
      $lat =$_POST['Customername'];
      echo "Customer Name:" . $lat . "-"; 
      echo "ENVIRON: " . $pat ; 

?>
```